Interrupted do-release-upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 during download phase
I pressed ctrl-C during download phase of sudo do-release-upgrade. Then I restarted the computer and now when I try to run sudo do-release-upgrade it says:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

When I run lsb_release -d it says I'm already on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. But I'm certain the install process was still on cca 15% of the download phase when I interrupted, so there's no way it fully upgraded. Nevertheless, everything seems to work fine (except connecting to an external monitor, but that could be unrelated).
I also tried replacing /etc/apt/sources.list with the content of sources.list.distUpgrade (i.e. I did sudo mv sources.list.distUpgrade sources.list). But sudo do-release-upgrade still returns the same thing.
I feel like I just have to tell Ubuntu that it is still version 23.10 and then it would normally upgrade to 24.04. Please help.
Thank you!!

Your system is now in state very hard to correct. The upgrade script run long enough to change software sources, reason why it reports 24.04 now, but didn't install the new packages nor performed the necessary cleanup, among many other steps. Better to install fresh (after backups) with a USB installer. You can keep the same partitions but additional software you'll have to reinstall.

What happens if you do a straight "apt update; apt upgrade" ?

@davidgo It'll upgrade most of the packages to the correct versions but it won't install new packages for the 24.04 release, it won't perform a proper cleanup and a few more steps coded in the release upgrade script.

Easiest is to restore the drive image of the older OS and then update to 24.04.

Hi all, thanks for your answers!
At some point I just got a popup saying something like "partial upgrade detected" and then it did all the upgrading and cleaning up. I was trying many things, so not really sure if something I did triggered this, or if it was automatic. Anyway, it all seems to work just fine.
